# WVD session host management

Tags: azure, windows-virtual-desktop

Is it viable to update session hosts in wvd using something like sccm? Or would we have to redeploy an updated image every time we wanted to patch the session hosts, what about dat files for windows defender?

Answer (score 0):

Windows Virtual Desktop Host session Image management became very handy with the benefit of Azure Shared Image Gallery and versioning, you can have a look on
[WVD Golden image Customization and how to update it using Shared Image Gallery](https://3tallah.com/wvd-golden-image-customization-and-updates-using-shared-image-gallery/) and this blogpost as well [Azure Shared Image Gallery and Windows Virtual Desktop](https://3tallah.com/azure-shared-image-gallery-and-windows-virtual-desktop/)